# Understanding a Sardinas-Patterson Theorem example

Tags: information-theory

If $C = \{0,01,011\}$, then $C_\infty = \{1,11\}$ which is disjoint from $C$. It follows from the Sardinas-Patterson Theorem that $C$ is uniquely decodable, as we have already seen.

What is the procedure to get from $C = \{0,01,011\}$ to $C_\infty = \{1,11\}$ ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proceeding as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardinas%E2%80%93Patterson_algorithm#Precise_description_of_the_algorithm),

$C_1=\{1,11\}$ (the result of removing a code word, when possible, from the left of any different code word)

$C_2=\emptyset$ (Nothing in $C_1$ begins with a code word, and no code word begins with anything in $C_1$.)

$C_i=\emptyset$ for $i>2$.

I’ll guess that $C_\infty$ means what it does [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=-f3qBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA153): the union of the $C_i$ for $i>0$, which in this case is $\{1,11\}$ and is disjoint from $C$.